# What is this bug on my Mint plant and is this harmful?

Tags: identification, bugs, mint

today I found these bugs on my Mint plant.
It's kinda just sit there and did nothing, but I haven't seen the bug before on my Mint (or my other plants), but currently only found this on my mint. What kind of bug is this? And is it harmful for the Mint or the other plants?
For the background info, I live in Tropical hot climate. So the temperature is hot all year long. I put the Mint plant on the shadier part to prevent the scorching afternoon sun. I tried to use the insect identifier app, but the result didn't seem really accurate.

[image]

THanks!

Comment: Looks like a mantis to me - they will eat all your bad bugs!